# How to pass a string containing double quotes from a jsp to a servlet through URL using get method

Tags: jsp, servlets, el

I want to set a jsp parameter to an attribute value which may contain special symbols, then use a form `GET` submit to pass the parameter to a servlet controller. For example, the parameter is:

`<input type="hidden" name="searchTerms" value="${sessionScope.combTerms}"></input>`

I noticed if `sessionScope.combTerms` contains double quotes, eg. `location:"LOC1"`, the controller will only receive the value of `searchTerms` to be `location:` in which the `LOC1"` disappeared. What should I do to make sure whatever string in `sessionScope.combTerms` is passed to the controller correctly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When filling HTML input values, always use [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html). It not only sanitizes the value from HTML entities which might risk your HTML to malform (a quote denotes end of attribute value, that's why the remnant of your value got lost), but it will also save you from [XSS injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) [attack risks](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) at places where you're redisplaying user-controlled input.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<input type="hidden" name="searchTerms" value="${fn:escapeXml(sessionScope.combTerms)}">
```

**No need** to `URLEncode` it. The webbrowser will already do it automagically. Try it yourself with an `&` in the value. You'll see that the webbrowser changes it `%26`. The webbrowser will also take care about parsing XML entities so that they end up correctly in the URL. I.e. you get `"` in server side, not `&#34;`.

Comment: This is beautiful!! This way is really what I was having in mind. A nice neat solution. Thank you very much Balus!! You are a genius.

Answer (score 3):

```
<% String st = str.replaceAll("\"", "&quot;");%> ,and use st instead of str.
```

Answer (score 1):

You encode the value before placing it into the form and then decode it in the serlvet.

(You might have already seen this as %20 in URL parameters)

Here are the respective classes.

http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Comment: Hi kazanaki, thanks for your answer. Hmhm... but I also want to display the `sessionScope.combTerms` using `<c:out value="${sessionScope.combTerms}"></c:out>`. After Encoded, the display is bad. So I would like to have a way more like decoded it in the .jsp for displaying purpose. Any more suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: put two attributes in the request - one encoded and one unencoded